# Como chamar o valor de uma variavel do javascript para utilizar no src?

Tags: javascript, html

tenho essa função em js que pega o nome do video que o usuario escolheu

```
function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m, key, value) {
        vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
}
var video = getUrlVars()["v"];
alert(video);
```

Gostaria de saber como eu faço para utilizar o valor obtido na variavel video na src abaixo:

```
<video width="502" height="360" id="Video1">
  <source src="COMO COLOCAR O VALOR DA VARIAVEL AQUI" type=video/webm>
</video>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defina um id na `<source id="valor"` com esse id, você vai ir no javascript lá na função e acrescentar o seguinte código:

```
document.getElementById("valor").setAttribute("src", nome da variavel);
```

Após colocar o nome da variável ele vai definir dentro do atributo "src" o seguinte valor da variável!

Comment: bem coloquei o codigo no final depois do alert  com a variavel video so que esta dando typeError, sabe o que pode tá errado?

Comment: Sabe me indicar qual a linha de código que ele cita estar errado?

Comment: bem resolvi era so usar window.load na função

Answer (score 2):

Sua função te retorna a variável `vars`, a mesma é uma string? Se eu não estiver errado, suponho que basta setar a variável como valor do atributo...

**JQuerry**

```
$("#Video1 > source").attr("src", vars);
```

**Javascript**

```
function myFunction() {
  var el = document.querySelector("#Video1 > source");
  el.setAttribute("src", vars);
}
```